# Consultar objetos filhos que satisfazem condição em objetos pai, Relacionamento com eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query, laravel-eloquent

Tenho em meu projeto duas tabelas que se relacionam, mas gostaria de fazer uma query consult que trouxesse todas as entidades filhos que um campo fosse igual a entidade pai, sendo para todas as entidades pai que satisfazem uma condição especifica.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Quero pegar todos as rodas que veiculo(classe pai) é vermelho, sendo que veiculos é uma tabela, rodas é outra, e cor(o vermelho) seja um campo. Exemplo ficticio. Neste caso quero todas as rodas somente.

Comment: "_trouxesse todas as entidades filhos que um campo fosse igual a entidade pai_" Você quer que um campo seja igual **a toda a entidade**? Por favor, tente ser um pouco mais claro.

Comment: Desculpa a confusão, quero pegar todos os veiculos que contem roda cromada, sendo que veiculos é uma tabela, rodas é outra, e tipo de roda(o cromado) seja um campo.
Exemplo ficticio

Comment: Jovem, perceba que não há **absolutamente nenhuma relação** entre o que você pede na sua pergunta e o que você diz no comentário anterior. Por favor, clique em [edit] e tente explicar melhor seu problema e dê um exemplo do que pretende fazer.

Comment: Desculpa, expliquei de forma realmente confusa, corrigi a explicação do que desejo editando o post, é um problema que tem tirado meu sono.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você não deu um exemplo real, usei as classes fictícias `Pai` e `Filho`

```
$dados = Pai::with('filhos')->where('coluna', 'algum valor')->get();
```

Neste caso, é preciso ter a relação mapeada no *model*

```
class Pai extends Model
{
    public function filhos() {
        return $this->hasMany(Filho::class);
    }
}
```

---

Aplicando ao exemplo de **`Veiculo`** e **`Roda`**

```
class Veiculo extends Model 
{
    public function rodas() {
        return $this->hasMany(Roda::class);
    }
}
```

O uso seria

```
$dados = Veiculo::with('rodas')->where('cor', 'vermelho')->get();
```

---

Pra retornar apenas as entidades filhas, é possível fazer um [`join`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins)

```
$dados = Roda::join('veiculos', function($query) {
    $query->on('veiculos.id', '=', 'rodas.veiculo_id');
    $query->where('veiculo.cor', '=', 'vermelho');
})
->get();
```

- [Documentação do Laravel sobre relacionamentos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships).
- [Documentação do método `join()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins).

Comment: O exemplo que preciso é diferente deste, Basicamente quero todos os filhos, no caso rodas que satisfazem uma condição do pai, é ai que fica um pouco mais dificil pq não sei como fazer isto.

Comment: Você quer todas as rodas onde o `id_veiculo` seja igual ao `id` de um veículo? @AndersoneyRodrigues

Comment: Exatamente. Mas não de um veiculo, mas de todos os veiculos que satisfazem a condição

Comment: @AndersoneyRodrigues Veja minha edição

Comment: Mas neste caso não quero  pegar as classes pai, quero somente as filho dentro da condição.

Comment: Não há como sua condição ser executada trazendo apenas rodas e não veiculos contendo rodas dentro do objeto?

Comment: @AndersoneyRodrigues Veja a parte final da resposta

Comment: Há alguma forma de remover alguns campos no retorno do objeto dados? Por exemplo, há varios campos que não quero que seja retornado nesta consulta.

Comment: Tem. Você pode fazer outra pergunta sobre isso.

Comment: Criei, se puder me ajudar ficarei grato